Converting the ChatGPT data export JSON to markdown conversations
In OpenAI ChatGPT, it's possible to download a data dump. Go to the top right corner to access the options, click "Settings", then "Data controls" and then "export. You will receive a download link. The download gives you a HTML file and a JSON file.
The JSON file seems to contain everything needed to reconstruct the conversations in Markdown. I'm looking for

a Windows program
which is free (gratis, open source preferred)
which converts the JSON file into multiple Markdown files
one Markdown file per conversation
names the file by date, time and auto-generated title (the title alone may not be unique)

